# TWILIO CiviCRM SMS Conversations wordpress webhook

Tags: wordpress, sms, twilio

I am trying to get SMS Conversations to work using Twilio. I have the outbound SMS working but the responses are not processed (inbound SMS to Civi). The given URL for the Webhook does not work. Is there a way I can figure out the correct webhook URL to input at Twilio?

Comment: Welcome Christopher!  Can you edit the question to link to the documentation that details the webhook you're using?  And also the URL you settled on?  Thanks!